# Definition of $\sigma(X_1,\dots, X_n)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space, and let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of RVs on the space. When studying martingales, I have always taken the definition of $\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ to be equal to the smallest $\sigma$-field such that each of $X_1$, $X_2,...,X_n$ is measurable. In other words, it is generated by the collection $\mathcal{A}:=\{ \{X_i\in B\} : 1\le i\le n, B\text{ Borel} \}$. Thus, $\mathcal{F}_n\subseteq\mathcal{F}$.

However, as I have started reading Chapter 6 of Durrett (Probability Theory and Examples) and the existence of Markov Chains, it seems like $\mathcal{F}_n$ is a subset of a finite product space and not a subset of $\mathcal{F}$ as I had thought...causing me with extreme confusion since I got through martingales ok with my definition.

If indeed my definition is wrong, I need further clarification. For example, the classic example of a martingale is a simple random walk $S_n=\xi_1+\cdots + \xi_n$ with filtration $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(\xi_1,\dots, \xi_n)$. In my definition, clearly $S_n\in\mathcal{F}_n$, but if $\mathcal{F}_n$ were part of a product space, there is no way that $S_n\in\mathcal{F}_n$ since $S_n$ is a function with domain $\Omega$, and does not have domain $\Omega\times\cdots\times\Omega$ ($n$ times)...since the inverse image $(S_n)^{-1}(B)\subseteq\Omega$. So for me, things seem to be inconsistent.

In short, I would appreciate if anyone could clarify these issues! Another possibility is that Durrett has abused notation in some way...

Comment: Looks like your definition is fine. In Theorem 6.1.1. of his text, Durrett defines $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_0,X_1,..,X_n)$.

Comment: He does, but in Equation (6.1.1) I believe $P$ is a measure on $(S^{\{0,1,\dots, n\}},\mathcal{S}^{\{0,1,\dots, n\}})$. Thus, the set $\{X_i\in B_i , 0\le i\le n\}\in \mathcal{S}^{\{0,1,\dots, n\}}$.  Given $P_{\mu}$ is a measure on the infinite sequence space and by looking at the proof of Theorem 6.1.1., I believe that $A\in \mathcal{F}_n$ is also in $\mathcal{S}^{0,1,\dots, n}$, in contrary to my definition. @manofbear